# Undefined return value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

This function returns an undefined value when it is executed. I want it to return true if the page is loaded and false if not:

```
function JLoad (url) {
        var uri = url + ' #div';
        $("#div").load(uri, {'bd': '1'}, function(response, status, xhr){
            if (status != "error"){
                if (window.history && window.history.pushState)
                {
                    window.history.pushState({}, 'Test', url);
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location.hash='!/'+url;
                }
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
```

This is part of the code used to request the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").on("click", function() {
        var url = $(this).attr("href").replace('./', '');
    console.log(JLoad(url));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The method `load` is Asynchronous, you can not return a value from the callback!

Comment: and you missed ; in `var uri = url + ' #div'`

Comment: @epascarello, could i replace the returns with something like "returnVal = true" and the put "return returnVal" at the end of the function?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the returned Boolean. Based on that we can give you an answer that will help out.

Comment: @epascarello I wish to apply a selected class to the link if the content is successfully loaded, with this code: if(JLoad(url)){
$("a").removeClass("active");$(this).addClass("active");}

Comment: @Josh just send an extra parameter (`$(this)`) to `JLoad` and do `add/removeClass` in the callback function. Or do what `Jload` does in the `click` handler.

Comment: So pass in the reference to the link and do the change in the callback of the load function. `function JLoad (url, linkElem) { ... linkElem.toggle("error", status != "error");` or pass in a callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because jQuery.load() is asynchronous, rewrite your function to accept a callback.

```
function JLoad (url, cb) {
    var uri = url + ' #div'
    $("#div").load(uri, {'bd': '1'}, function(response, status, xhr){
        if (status != "error"){
            if (window.history && window.history.pushState)
            {
                window.history.pushState({}, 'Test', url);
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.hash='!/'+url;
            }
            cb(true);
        } else{
            cb(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function() {
        var $link = $(this),
            url = $link.attr("href").replace('./', '');

        JLoad(url, function(successful) {
            if (successful) {
                $("a").removeClass("active");
                $link.addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I was just about to say, I had to add "var $link = $(this);". But thank you so much for your help!